# Multiple AjaxCheckBox did not work to control setEnabled

Tags: java, wicket

I'm quite new using Wicket framework.

Currently I'm working on to set the `setEnabled` of the `TextField`. In my case, I have two `TextField` to control using `AjaxCheckbox`. During my trial, I have no issue to `setEnabled` for the first `TextField`, but when I add second `TextField` with `AjaxCheckbox`, the second one didn't work, only the first one.

Is there something that I missed out?

The first one

```
    mobileNo = new TextField<String>("mobileNo", new PropertyModel<String>(getModelObject(), "mobileNo")) {
        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
           setEnabled(mobileNoCheckBoxValue); 
        }
    };
    mobileNo.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    form.add(mobileNo);

    AjaxCheckBox mobileNoCheckBox = new AjaxCheckBox("mobileNoCheckBox", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(this, "mobileNoCheckBoxValue")) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                target.add(mobileNo);
        }
    };

    form.add(mobileNoCheckBox);
```

and the second one

```
    appliedAmount = new TextField<BigDecimal>("appliedAmount", new BigDecimalFormatProperty<BigDecimal>(getModel(), "appliedAmount"))    {
        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
           setEnabled(appliedAmountCheckBoxValue); 
        }
    };
    appliedAmount.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    form.add(appliedAmount);

    AjaxCheckBox appliedAmountCheckBox = new AjaxCheckBox("appliedAmountCheckBox", new PropertyModel(this, "appliedAmountCheckBoxValue")) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(appliedAmount);
        }
    };
    form.add(appliedAmountCheckBox);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your HTML code and make sure you use different `id` attribute values for `<input type="checkbox" .../>`.

If you have `id` attribute in your HTML template then better remove it completely and let Wicket to auto-generate it. The ids must be unique by HTML specification. But also Wicket uses them to lookup the HTML elements when sending their values with Ajax.
I guess when you click the second checkbox Wicket sends the state of the first one, which does not toggle.